# My script is using .encode('utf-8') a lot. I feel like im doing something wrong

Tags: python, encoding

The problem i have with this script is that i have to keep calling `.encode('utf-8')` and this doesn't seem very zen to me. I must be doing something wrong.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" Simple rss to html converter """

__version__ = "0.0.1"
__author__ = "Ricky L Wilson"

import StringIO
from feedparser import parse as parsefeed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def entry2html(**kwargs):
    """ Format feedparser entry """
    title = kwargs['title'].encode('utf-8')
    link = kwargs['link'].encode('utf-8')
    description = kwargs['description'].encode('utf-8')
    template = """
    <h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
    <a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
    <span class='description'>{description}</span>
    """
    return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description)


def convert_feed(**kwargs):
    """ Main loop """
    out = StringIO.StringIO("")
    for entry in parsefeed(kwargs['url']).entries:
        title = entry['title']
        link = entry['link']
        description = entry['description']
        print >> out, entry2html(title=title, link=link, description=description)
    return bs(out.getvalue(), 'lxml').prettify()

def save_file(url, fname):
    ''' Save data to disc'''
    with open(fname, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(convert_feed(url=url).encode('utf-8'))

print save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
```

PS. If i remove any of them the script will break.

I tried putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file but that didn't fix it. i got this error.

```
C:\Python27>python rss2html.py
  File "rss2html.py", line 40
    save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Python27>python rss2html.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rss2html.py", line 40, in <module>
    save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
  File "rss2html.py", line 38, in save_file
    file_object.write(convert_feed(url=url))
  File "rss2html.py", line 32, in convert_feed
    print >> out, entry2html(title=title, link=link, description=description)
  File "rss2html.py", line 22, in entry2html
    return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 172: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` coding directive just tells the interpreter how to decode the script file itself, it has no bearing on how script encodes or decodes external data. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1):

Your kwargs are unicode strings. You should define your template as a unicode string as well, by using the `u` prefix, then encode once at the end.

```
template = u"""
<h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
<a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
<span class='description'>{description}</span>
"""
return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: File "rss2html.py", line 22, in entry2html
   return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description).encode('utf-8')
nicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You haven't followed my answer: `template` needs to be a unicode string, with a `u` prefix.

Comment: I did that but it raised the exception.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you are now using. Also try doing it in two stages; `t = template.format(...)` then `return t.encode('utf-8')` to see which line is actually raising that exception.

Comment: I have put the code up for review im interested in what else is wrong with it.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167467/a-python-script-to-convert-an-rss-feed-to-html

Comment: What's wrong with it is that the flatten_unicode_keys function is **completely pointless**. The thing that fixed your code is using the `u` prefix on the template.

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out, let me know what you guys think.
Is this method better then all those .encode('utf-8') calls or is this a hack and their is still a more pythonic way to eliminate the `.encode('utf-8')` calls.

**Here is the new script**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Simple rss to html converter """

__version__ = "0.0.1"
__author__ = "Ricky L Wilson"

import StringIO
from feedparser import parse as parsefeed
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def flatten_unicode_keys(d):
    '''pass unicode keywords to **kwargs '''
    for k in d:
        if isinstance(k, unicode):
            v = d[k]
            del d[k]
            d[str(k)] = v

def entry2html(**kwargs):
    """ Format feedparser entry """
    flatten_unicode_keys(kwargs)
    title = kwargs['title']
    link = kwargs['link']
    description = kwargs['description']
    template = """
    <h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
    <a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
    <span class='description'>{description}</span>
    """
    return template.format(title=title, link=link, description=description)


def convert_feed(**kwargs):
    """ Main loop """
    out = StringIO.StringIO("")
    for entry in parsefeed(kwargs['url']).entries:
        title = entry['title']
        link = entry['link']
        description = entry['description']
        print >> out, entry2html(title=title, link=link, description=description)
    return bs(out.getvalue(), 'lxml').prettify()

def save_file(url, fname):
    ''' Save data to disc'''
    with open(fname, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(convert_feed(url=url))

save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
```

Comment: Please don't do this. As mentioned in the comments & answers of [your new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944274/could-someone-explain-how-this-function-works-so-i-can-document-it#44944390) it's not safe to add or remove keys from a dict that you're iterating over. Furthermore, `str(k)` will raise `UnicodeEncodeError` if `k` contains Unicode codepoints outside the 7 bit ASCII range. FWIW, this task would be easier if you were using Python 3...

Comment: Plus, as I also mention, this has nothing whatever to do with the problem you were actually having. The initial error was happening because the *value* of the dictionary key was unicode; this function only converts the *key* into a string, leaving the value alone, so could not possibly fix the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the newest version of the script no more `flatten_unicode_keys(d)`
no more `StringIO` and no more `for loops` I think this is way more pythonic then the past versions. Its also faster.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Simple RSS to HTML converter."""

__version__ = "0.0.2"
__author__ = "Ricky L Wilson"

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from feedparser import parse as parse_feed


TEMPLATE = u"""
<h2 class='title'>{title}</h2>
<a class='link' href='{link}'>{title}</a>
<span class='description'>{summary}</span>
"""

def entry_to_html(**kwargs):
    """Formats feedparser entry."""
    return TEMPLATE.format(**kwargs).encode('utf-8')


def convert_feed(url):
    """Main loop."""
    html_fragments = [entry_to_html(**entry) for entry in parse_feed(url).entries]
    return BeautifulSoup("\n".join(html_fragments), 'lxml').prettify()


def save_file(url, filename):
    """Saves data to disc."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(convert_feed(url).encode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    save_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds', 'index.html')
    with open('index.html') as fobj:
        print fobj.read()
```